# Convert Javascript Date object to PST time zone

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to pick a future date from calender, suppose the date I am selecting is `10/14/2014`, now what I want is to send the date with the time to server, so that at server end it always reaches as 6am time in PST timezone and the format of date should be UTC.

What I am doing is

`targetDate = new Date($("#calendar").val());
 targetDate = targetDate.toUTCString();
 targetDate = targetDate.addHours(14);`

My understanding is that PST timezone is -8:00 so I have added 14 hours to the UTC time so that time becomes 6:00am PST

The problem I am facing is that it is not letting me to add 14 hours since the object has already been converted to string.

addHours is the custom function I am having to add the hours in given time.

If I write

`targetDate = new Date($("#calendar").val());
 targetDate = targetDate.addHours(14);
 targetDate = targetDate.toUTCString();`

then it works good but in this case problem is time will always be different when the request is coming from different timezones.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a good starting point: http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time .  For a very quick warning, PST is not always 8 hours behind, for part of the year it is 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggest you look at DateJS http://code.google.com/p/datejs/ or http://www.datejs.com/. Handles PDT for you.

Here is an alternative for you:

Use: Date.UTC(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, ms)

Example:
For 1 Jan 2013 6AM PST

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1, 14, 0, 0))   
console.log(date.toUTCString());
```

Prints: "Tue, 01 Jan 2013 14:00:00 GMT"

Comment: is there anyway without using any 3rd party js file?

Comment: @Ankush please try this and let me know

Comment: @raghavv : Thankyou sir you made my life easy. Works perfect as per my requirement.

Comment: -1 for datejs.  It's a dead library with many bugs and no foreseable future.

Comment: why is this accepted answer ? the question clearly states UTC to PST but this answer is proposing the exact opposite !!!

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

```js
var myDate = new Date(1633071599000)
var pstDate = myDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
})
console.log(pstDate)
```

Which outputs `"9/30/2021, 11:59:59 PM"`

Answer (score 8):

You said:

> My understanding is that PST timezone is -8:00 so I have added 14 hours to the UTC time so that time becomes 6:00am PST

Uh - no.  That will put you on the following day.  If you wanted to stay in PST, you would *subtract* 8 hours from the UTC time.  `-8:00` means that it is 8 hours *behind* UTC.

However, the Pacific Time zone isn't just fixed at PST.  It alternates between PST (-8) and PDT (-7) for daylight saving time.  In order to determine the correct offset, you need to use a library that implements the TZDB database.  Refer to [this duplicate answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17476856/634824).

The only way to do it without a fancy library is to actually *be* in the pacific time zone.  JavaScript will convert UTC dates to the local time zone for display, and it will use the correct offset.  But it only knows about the *local* time zone.  If Pacific Time is not your local time zone, then you must use a library.

Answer (score 3):

```
var date = new Date();
var utcDate = new Date(date.toUTCString());
utcDate.setHours(utcDate.getHours()-8);
var usDate = new Date(utcDate);
console.log(usDate);
```

Comment: this is a good quick fix but its not always -8 hours right? day light savings time

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('tmp_button-48523').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let d = new Date();
  let localTime = d.getTime();
  let localOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
  let utc = localTime + localOffset;
  let target_offset = -7;//PST from UTC 7 hours behind right now, will need to fix for daylight
  let los_angles = utc+(3600000*target_offset);
  nd = new Date(los_angles);
  let current_day = nd.getDay();
  let hours = nd.getHours();
  let mins = nd.getMinutes();
alert("los_angles time is " + nd.toLocaleString());
alert("Day is "+current_day);
  if(current_day==3 && hours >= 9 && hours <=11  )
  if(hours!=11 && mins >= 45)
  fbq('track', 'LT-Login');
}, false);

function fbq(p1,p2){
alert(p1);
}
```

```html
<button id="tmp_button-48523">
Click me!
</button>
```

Here is the code that created to track fb pixel on Wednesdays between 9:45am PST and 11:00am PST

Answer (score 1):

I think the question asks how to convert UTC to PST time (as indicated on the title). I'm making assumption that the local time is in pacific time (i.e. the server or local web browser etc)

if that's the case, in order to convert UTC time to local PST just do this

```
// Create date object from datetime (Assume this is the UTC /GMT) time
var date = new Date('Tue, 21 Apr 2020 09:20:30 GMT');
   
// Covert to local PST datetime, AGAIN this only works if the server/browser is in PST
date.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly comment:

> I need to pick a future date from calender, suppose the date I am
>   selecting is 10/14/2014,

Since there isn't a 14th month, I suppose you mean 14 October, 2014. Since this is an international forum, better to use an unambiguous format.

> … and the format of date should be UTC

UTC is not a format, it's a standard time.

I think you are confused. If you want say 2014-10-14T06:00:00-08:00 in UTC, then the equivalent is 2014-10-14T14:00:00Z.

You are using the `toUTCString` method, but it is implementation dependent, so you'll get different results in different browsers. You probably want the `toISOString` method, but it's ES5 and not implemented in all browsers.

You need to provide some examples of how you want times to be converted, otherwise you may as well just get the date in ISO8601 format and append "T14:00:00Z" to it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can simply add 14 hours before converting to UTC.

Or you can create a new Date object out of the UTC string:

```
var date = new Date();
date = date.addHours(14);
var dateUTC = new Date(date.toUTCString());
```

Comment: If I create a new object at the end, it will again give me the timezone of the user and not UTC, I need to send in UTC format