# Converting Unix Timestamp to PST

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time, timezone

Hi I have a json which I am getting some data. There the time format I am getting is like

**1367023443000**

I want to convert this to the Normal PST format. Ive tried using Javascript`s Date method. Passed the Unix time to the Date method,

```
var now = new Date(1367023443000);
```

I am getting only IST value, But not PST. What should I do here to convert the Unix timestamp to PST?

Comment: Javascript don't play nice with timezones. Use momentjs if you need to date time conversion.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not actually in the US Pacific Time zone, the only way to do this reliably in JavaScript is with a library that implements the TZDB database.  [I list several of them here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).

For example, using [walltime-js](https://github.com/sproutsocial/walltime-js) library, you can do the following:

```
var date = new Date(1367023443000);
var pacific = WallTime.UTCToWallTime(date, "America/Los_Angeles");
var s = pacific.toDateString() + ' ' + pacific.toFormattedTime();

// output:  "Fri Apr 26 2013 5:44 PM"
```

You can't just add or subtract a fixed number, because the target time zone may use a different offset depending on exactly what date you're talking about.  This is primarily due to Daylight Saving Time, but also because time zones have changed over time.