# How to convert from date.now to pacific time

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

On my current project, I have to implement elapsed time for each user and display it on the webpage.
However, using the date.now will return utc and I would like to get it in pacific time. I googled and researched through online but could not get it to work... Is there a way to convert from utc to pacific time?

Comment: Try this: 'var usaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});', don't forget to change the timezone.

Comment: Intention is to get time in pacific is fine. To keep it consistent, assume all in `UTC` for any calculations and finally use `toLocaleDateString` for display purpose. All your code will be intuitive in that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```js
const event = new Date(Date.now());

const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('us-PT', options));
```

Where "us" is the "United States" and "PT" is "Pacific-Time"
To see more go to  [MDN web docs Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: Thank you Daniel I will take a look at it!!

Answer (score 0):

I see a few options you have at hand.

## Option 1 - use an external library (moment / date-fns)

Consider using these libraries if your app is going to heavily rely on timezones, dates etc.

For example:

`moment.tz(12345678, "America/Los_Angeles") // 12345678 being your Date timestamp`

See more info here:

[date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)
[moment](https://momentjs.com/)

## Option 2 - you need to use vanilla JS

Found a few answers on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854105/convert-javascript-date-object-to-pst-time-zone), but I couldn't see any of them being long term reliable (because of savings time etc.) - I might be wrong about it, but I resort to date/time libraries when my app heavily uses the same.

Comment: Thank you Antonio I will take a look at the above link!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles' });
const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles' });
const datetime = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles' });
```

Hope it helps others save time.